# PHP code for a array on Post request - Retrofit

Tags: php, post, retrofit

I'm developing a **retrofit android** app that sends an array of images to a web server by POST method, which is already working, I used as a basis [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).

My difficulty is receive the request that it is like this:

```
Request URL:http://172.16.10.51:8888/upload.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Provisional headers are shown
Accept-Encoding:gzip
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:301185
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=7c3e7190-b3c8-4957-b0a3-c9cee4d736a9
Host:172.16.10.51:8888
User-Agent:okhttp/3.10.0
--7c3e7190-b3c8-4957-b0a3-c9cee4d736a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0


--7c3e7190-b3c8-4957-b0a3-c9cee4d736a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"; filename="PANO_20180613_144953.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 151398

<decoded picture string> 

--7c3e7190-b3c8-4957-b0a3-c9cee4d736a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1"; filename="PANO_20180613_144929.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 149205

<decoded picture string>

--7c3e7190-b3c8-4957-b0a3-c9cee4d736a9--
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:47
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 15 Jun 2018 16:30:18 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.12 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.12
```

obs * where it says "decoded picture string" are the hundreds of characters representing the image

I would like to know how to mount a file in php that interprets this request and image array and save it in a certain folder on the server, some thing like this:

```
<?php

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_dir = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $response = array();

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_FILES["file"])) {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
            $success = true;
            $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
        } else {
            $success = false;
            $message = "Error while uploading ". $target_dir;
        }
    } else {
        $success = false;
        $message = "Campos incorretos";
    }

    $response["success"] = $success;
    $response["message"] = $message;
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this array of pictures on PHP:

```
<?php

    $target_dir = "uploads/";

    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= 2) {// this based on size of array

        $target_dir = $target_dir .basename($_FILES[$i]["name"]);
        $response = array();

        if (isset($_FILES[$i])) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$i]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
                $success = true;
                $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
            } else {
                $success = false;
                $message = "Error while uploading ". $target_dir;
            }
        } else {
            $success = false;
            $message = "Campos incorretos";
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $response["success"] = $success;
    $response["message"] = $message;
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```